# Is TestFX compatible with Java 7?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx-2, testfx

Running the following snippet (with JDK 7 set in Eclipse):

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.testfx.framework.junit.ApplicationTest;

public class BasicTestFxTest extends ApplicationTest 
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene(null, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println("This is not a test.");
    }
}
```

Results in the following exception:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/testfx/framework/junit/ApplicationTest : Unsupported major.minor
>   version 52.0  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:685)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Note: I am using testfx-core and testfx-junit 4.0.1-alpha.

Answer (score 1):

It  is fixed in version 4 ([TestFX 4.0.0-alpha — February 27, 2015](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX/pull/103)  - #103) but version 4 is in alpha phase

> (fix) Service: Fix compatibility to Java 7 and JavaFX 2. (#103) — 1
>   commit

The issue: https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX/pull/103

Comment: It is still broken in 4.0.4-alpha. Also, that commit doesn't look like it would fix the problem I'm seeing. At least they're aware of the compatibility issue!

Comment: I think the problem is that the binary was compiled against Java 8.