# Latest version of testfx supported in java 7

Tags: javafx, testfx

The closest I can find for this is [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40220306/is-testfx-compatible-with-java-7), but that seems to say the 4.0.0-alpha has issues since it was compiled against java 8. Currently, we're using 3.1.2, but this is definitely missing some functionality. Does anyone have any word on a later version that's usable?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but I think Java 7 stopped being publicly supported long ago. Even if you have a commercial Oracle support license, JavaFX itself in Java 7 compatible versions (so JavaFX 2.x) is missing considerable functionality compared to JavaFX 8 , 9, and 10. I think it's highly unlikely any versions of TextFX that are supported in Java 7 are being maintained.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of, but our company is stuck on 1.7 until mid-year (for sure this time guys™). So, we're trying to support this from 1.7 until then.